# Hangman Program 2

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, swift2, element

I have asked a question before about this program, but it seems that not all problems are resolved. I am currently experiencing an error that states: "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '_Element' (aka 'Character') on the "guard let indexInWord" line:

```
    guard let letterIndex = letters.indexOf(sender)
        else { return }

    let letter = letterArray[letterIndex]
    guard let indexInWord = word.characters.indexOf(letter)
        else {
            print("no such letter in this word")
            return
        }

    // since we have spaces between dashes, we need to calc index this way
    let indexInDashedString = indexInWord * 2

    var dashString = wordLabel.text
    dashString[indexInDashedString] = letter
    wordLabel.text = dashString
```

I tried converting the String 'letter' to Character but it only resulted in more errors. I was wondering how I can possibly convert String to argument type "_Element." Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to treat a string like a list in swift, mostly because the String.characters is not a typical array. Running a for loop on that works, but if you are looking for a specific character given an index, it is a bit more difficult. What I like doing is adding this function to the string class.

```
extenstion String {
    func getChars() -> [String] {
        var chars:[String] = []
        for char in characters {
            chars.append(String(char))
        }
        return chars
    }
}
```

I would use this to define a variable when you receive input, then check this instead of String.characters